How can I create the password field using TextInput widget in .slint file?
everyone.
According to my experience, slint is a frontend library.
I was making a project that combined Rust and slint.
I encountered an issue while creating a password field using TextInput widget in a .slint file. One line: I set it to true but it doesn't work.
Two lines appear like this.
I hope you can help me with this issue.
I would be more grateful if you could send me an example code.
We salute your efforts in developing new technologies.

TextInput has a input-type property that can be set to password.
But the best is to use the LineEdit widget which has the same property:
import { LineEdit } from "std-widgets.slint";

component Example {
    LineEdit {
        input-type: password;
    }
}


Than you for your reply. But I want to change the Background of Input. In my experience, It isn't able to change the background of lineEidt. So I used the  TextField.
Could you explain about the change the background of LineEidt.
